# Why do I see this little red dot when there isn't a new email?

Tags: email, outlook.com, outlook-365, microsoft-office

Every now and then I see this little red dot on the tab (which I'm assuming is shown to indicate a new incoming/unread email). I use the web version of Outlook FWIW.

[image]

However, when I switch back to the tab, I do not see any new emails. Refreshing the page also doesn't help. It happens very frequently - like 5-10 times a day during a shift.

What is Outlook trying to tell me?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that's frustrating.  it supposed to be an alert that you have new unread mail, but for me, it seems to also mean new unread 'what's new' too.  just to the left my name icon, in the upper right corner, is an icon that looks like trapezoid, or a bullhorn speaker,...click on that and acknowledge the news by scrolling through the list of items.  then click to exit.  now you might see, like I did, my red dot go away!

[image: what's new]

Comment: I have no such icon showing and yet the red dot appears "randomly" several times a day. I have no rules or filters defined, so it's not that email is coming in and being automatically handled either. It just seems like Outlook is a bit needy and attention-seeking...

Answer (score 1):

I've been getting that too. I just scrolled to the top of my folder list and clicked on Inbox (even though I was already in my Inbox) and the dot cleared and hasn't come back.

Seems even though I had no new emails, and was already in my Inbox, just acknowledging it in the system by CLICKING inbox, was enough to clear it. Let's hope it lasts!

Answer (score -1):

It's absolutely a ploy to get you to click on the tab when the advertisement changes/refreshes. The point of the favicon changing (on every other site in the world) is to let you know you have a new notification (in this case, an email) to view. In Microsoft's case, they're telling you they want you to see another marketing link. I stopped using Microsoft as my primary email years ago due to this because I couldn't trust it to keep it open in a tab all day. I still check it a couple times per day, but it's never open in the background anymore because the red dot clickbait has been an effective way to scare me off their platform.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/155492)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Going to chime in and agree with the other commenters. The red dot shows up when the advertisement on the side of your screen changes in your inbox. Very annoying! It seems like Microsoft has a couple employees downvoting everyone who brings this up too lol. Add me to the list of people who have moved to another email service due to this!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/155510)

Answer (score -2):

I muted the Outlook tab, and it appeared to stop showing the red dot for a time. Personally I think MS are not doing anything to stop the red dot, even though lots of users request they disable it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

My guess it that it appears to get to you look at the tab, for advertising purposes.
i.e. it's intentional by Outlook

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).